# Statistical rationale for variable (genes) selection

Tags: classification, mathematical-statistics, variance, feature-selection, standard-deviation

When it comes to selection of a subset of variables from a big data matrix, such as a gene expression matrix, I have come across some publications that have picked a somewhat arbitrary approach to select for the most informative variables, e.g. filtering data based on N top percent of variance, coefficient of variation, median absolute deviation, or standard deviation.

1. Which one of these terms mentioned above can provide a less biased selection and is statistically more significant (specially in gene expression data?)
2. I have seen such filtering criteria (based on variance) as below in a paper ([link](https://www.nature.com/articles/onc2010196)) but I can not figure out why these filtering steps have been applied. For example, wouldn't it be enough to select a subset of variable only based on n top percent of IQR?

> *"To enrich highly informative probe sets, we applied three filters: probe sets had to be among the top 2% of all probe sets with regard to their variance, their maximum minus median expression and their 90% quantile minus median expression across all specimens."*

Since I am not an statistician I would appreciate someone could explain these in simple words.

Comment: I suspect _coefficient of variance_ to be a typo for _coefficient of variation_. If not, your source is unreliable. As for your question, maximum, median and variance are defined in just about every introductory text. At that level, the 90% quantile is perhaps more commonly called the 90% percentile. Maximum, median and percentiles are expressed in terms of the original units, so you can look at their differences. (Not a biologist, so I don't know what gene expression is precisely. Not a statistician either.)

Comment: The issue is substantive, I imagine, that IQR would not use any of the detailed information above the upper quartile.

Comment: @nickCox thanks for mentioning the typo. I am aware of definitions of the terms, but what I don't understand is that what statistical power they have add by doing selection based on those 3 criteria. why not, for example, only top 2 % of most variable genes?
PS: gene expression matrix is relative measures of several thousands of genes under investigation across individuals (patients) in an experiments.

Comment: I think you're talking about someone's scientific judgement here. Either someone explains why in your literature, or 2% is just being offered as what supposedly works well. There is no statistical argument behind 2% that follows from definitions of quantiles or variance. Note that there is a strict statistical meaning to  _power_  within statistical inference; I sense you're using the word informally and without wanting or needing to define it, which is fine by me, but it's best to avoid ambiguity.